# Solving a logarithmic system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, systems-of-equations

I am working on a test study guide and I can't seem to get the correct answer for this system of equations:
\begin{align*}
    \ln(x) &= 3\ln(y) \\
    \ 3^x &= 27^y
\end{align*}

I'm not really sure how to go about solving this equation, so any help/direction would be much appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure those are the correct equations you were given?

Comment: Maybe the second equation was supposed to be $3^x=27^y$?

Comment: Yes I just checked my guide again and the it is in fact 27^y not 27y. This makes it a lot more easier than I thought it was, my mistake!

Comment: @user143171 In that case, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Notice

$$ \ln x = 2 \ln y \iff \ln x = \ln y^2 \iff x = y^2 $$
and
$$ 3^x = 27 y \iff 3^x = 3^3 y \iff 3^{x-3} = y \iff 3^{y^2 - 3} = y \iff \ln 3 ( y^2 - 3) = y \iff y^2 - 3  - \frac{y}{\ln 3} = 0 \iff y^2 - \frac{1}{\ln 3} y - 3 = 0$$

This is a quadratic equation, which you can easily solve.

Comment: $\ln 3 ( y^2 - 3) = y$ is wrong, it should be $(\ln 3) ( y^2 - 3) =\ln y$.  The equation is no longer quadratic and it doesn't look easy.

Comment: And you should have $3\ln y$ in the first line not $2\ln y$.

Comment: Please see the comment posted by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation says that $x,y>0$ and then it's equivalent to $x=e^{\ln x}=e^{3\ln y}=e^{\ln y^3}=y^3$.

The second equation is equivalent to $x=3y$ by taking a logarithm, so we have
$$3y=y^3\Longleftrightarrow y(y-\sqrt3)(y+\sqrt3)=0$$
and the only solution is $y=\sqrt3$, which gives $x=3\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 0):

This will look something like the rest of the answers (since the principles underlying the calculations are simple), but hopefully this avoids the "rejection" issue.

Starting from

$$ \ 3^x \ = \ 27^y \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 3^x \ =  \ (3^3)^y \ = \ 3^{3y} \ \ $$

we use the "common base" method you learn early on to establish that $ \ x = 3y \ $ .  Replacing this in the first equation produces

$$ \ln (3y) \ = \ 3 \ \ln (y)   \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \ln \ 3 \ +  \ \ln \ y \ = \ 3 \ \ln \ y \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ 2 \ \ln \ y \ = \ \ln \ 3  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \ln \ y \ = \ \frac{1}{2} \ln \ 3 \ = \ \ln \ 3^{1/2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  y \ = \ 3^{1/2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ x \ = \ 3 \ \cdot \ 3^{1/2} \ \ . $$

Arranging to exponentiate at the end can only produce a positive value, and thereby dodges the "spurious solution" issue.